# Spring security filter chain is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I am using Spring Security to validate my `GET` and `POST` requests. The auth mechanisms for `GET` and `POST` are not the same. The below snippet is from my `SecurityConfig`s configure method.

`FilterA` is for `GET` request and I have defined a `customBAuthenticationManager` bean which implements `AuthenticationManager` for it.

`FilterB` is for `POST` requests and I have defined `customAuthProvider` with `UserDetails` service. These `GET` and `POST` requests work fine when added alone. But when both these filters are added  one after the other, first request in the filter chain fails but the second request works fine.

For instance, with the below code, my `POST` request works fine but `GET` request (1st in the chain) throws 401 error. If I swap the order of `GET` and `POST`, then the `GET` would work fine but `POST` (1st in the chain) throws 403 error.

But all the cases, I could see that the custom authentication manager/provider work fine.

Can someone help me understand what's going wrong here?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        FilterA filtera = new FilterA();
        filtera.setCheckForPrincipalChanges(true);
        filtera.setAuthenticationManager(customBAuthenticationManager());

        FilterB filterb = new FilterB();
        filterb.setCheckForPrincipalChanges(true);
        filterb.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());

        httpSecurity
            .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                    .disable()
                .and()
            .mvcMatcher("/**")
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .requestCache()
                .requestCache(getHttpSessionRequestCache())
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .and()
                .and()
            .addFilter(filtera)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/getrequest/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .addFilter(filterb)
            .authenticationProvider(customAauthProvider())
            .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/postrequest/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/different-open-request/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
```

Tried changing the order of the filters in filter chain. Tried removing one of the request from the filter chain, and that works fine.

Comment: Can you share `FilterA` and `FilterB`?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to you use AuthenticationEntryPoint
and then add filters before or after entryPoint.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .and().requestCache().requestCache(getHttpSessionRequestCache())
            .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntrypoint)
            .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilterAfter(new myAFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).addFilter(new Filter() {
                @Override
                public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
                }
            });
}
```